# Windows 11 installation error 0x80070570

Tags: windows, laptop, installation, windows-installation, windows-11

I recently bought an HP Pavilion bb0501 with windows 11 preinstalled, so I decided to do a clean install of windows 11 to remove the bloatware that new laptops always contain. I downloaded the iso and created a installation media using Rufus, then I booted from the USB.
When I was to manage the partitions, the SSD wasn't detected by windows, so I followed this tutorial from official HP page that applies to 11th gen Intel processors

https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-f2000-laptop-pc-series/35900344/model/35900346/document/c06983517?docNotFound=true

After doing this, the SSD was successfully detected and I wipe the disk to do a clean install.
During windows installation, a message appears saying: "Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or mising. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation. Error code: 0x80070570"
In the past I have installed windows many times, but this is the first time a error appears I don't know what to do.

***Edit:*** Finally, I could fix this problem. Apparently, the iso file was corrupted, I checked the file hash and it was different. Now I am installing Windows 10 and later I will update it to windows 11 using Windows update. During the installation I had to use the Intel RST driver because the M.2 SSD wasn't detected by the installer. After selecting this driver, the installation went normally. Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't use Rufus for this.  It is an incredible piece of software but what you want to use is the Windows 11 [media creation tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d).

Comment: Make sure you get all the Drivers you need.

Comment: @John what another drivers should I need?, I extracted Intel RST driver (RAID) to the installation media and selected it during installation .

Comment: Use the HP Driver Update App to get all the drivers you need.

Comment: Why? Intel RST is only required for RAID. Do you have more than one drive installed with the intention of setting up a RAID? I agree with using the Media Creation Tool only because it sounds like the ISO you used was possibly corrupt. Be sure you disable Intel RST within the firmware before you try and install Windows 11

Comment: @Ramhound I installed Intel RST because without it, the PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD weren't detected by Windows installer

Comment: @juanafanador07 - That is likely due to the fact Intel RST is enabled within the firmware.  You can disable it.  I stand by the fact the ISO is likely corrupted, unexplained installer issues, are typically caused by corrupt ISO files.

Comment: I decided to install windows 10 and update it to windows 11 through windows update. During the installation of windows 10, I also had to select the Intel RST driver, after this, the installation went normally. Apparently, the Windows 11 iso that I used was corrupted (I checked the hash and it was different). Thanks for the help.